# to make call when power button is pressed twice

Tags: android, button, call

Am pretty new to android.I want to know whether it is possible to make a call to a specified number when the power button is pressed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can override power button click events like this:

```
long last_click = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            // Check if power button was pressed twice in last second
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - last_click) <= 1000) {
                // Make call if pressed twice
                call();
                return true;
            }
            last_click = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    public void call() {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
```

Add call permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thank u for the code. But am getting an error in this line "dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)", it says this method must return a  result of type boolean.